# Log4j 1.x to Log4j 2 Migration: BasicConfigurator and DOMConfigurator missing

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am migrating a large application from Log4j 1.2.12 to Log4j 2.1.17. After replacing the dependencies in the build.gradle many classes are now showing errors. The official [Apache Migration Guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) unfortunately doesn't mention the problems I encounter. For your information: I'm doing the option 2 of the guide "Option 2: convert your application to the Log4j 2 API (log4j-api)" (the option 1 bridge is not applicable due to constraints listed in the guide). The following lines of code are being shown as an error:

```
// [...]
import org.apache.logging.log4j.BasicConfigurator; // ERROR 
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ConsoleAppender; // ERROR 
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.PropertyConfigurator; // ERROR 
import org.apache.logging.log4j.SimpleLayout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator; // ERROR 

public class DefaultLogStrategy implements LogStrategy {
// [...]
```

The guide says just to add logging between apache and log4j (in the import statements). Especially PropertyConfigurator and DOMConfigurator are classes for which I wonder if they are still in Log4j2 and if yes, why their eventual abscence has not been mentioned by the guide.

For the record: I'm aware that you don't need to use DOMConfigurator or BasicConfigurator. Yet I want to keep it unless I absolutely have to make big changes to the code base.

EDIT: A general problem for me is now that I used to have only a single jar file in the project. The migration requires me to have 2 jars (build.gradle files show):

```
  // BEFORE
  dependencies {
        // [...]
        libraryImplementation 'log4j:log4j:1.2.12'
    }


  // AFTER
  dependencies {
       // [...]
        implementation group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.17.1'
        implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1")
    }
```

Comment: Those classes does not exist in Log4j 2.x. If you want some help replacing them, please add some code that uses them and explain what is your `DefaultLogStrategy` class doing.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?